# How to remove the double quote when the value is empty in Spark?

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, pyspark

I would like to remove the double-quotes "" when the value is empty when registering my CSV in S3 with the method df.write.save() of Spark

Spark Version : 2.4.0

Python Version : 3.6.5

Here is my code in Python for load the csv file:

```py
df = spark.read.load(
    path('in'),
    format = 'csv',
    delimiter = '|',
    encoding = 'utf-8',
    header = 'true'
)
```

The loaded CSV file:

```
|id|first_name|last_name|zip_code|
|1 |          |Elsner   |57315   |
|2 |Noelle    |         |        |
|3 |James     |Moser    |48256   |
```

Here is my code in Python for write the csv file:

```py
df.write.save(
    path('out'),
    format = 'csv',
    delimiter = '|',
    header = 'true'
)
```

The CSV file written:

```
|id|first_name|last_name|zip_code|
|1 |""        |Elsner   |57315   |
|2 |Noelle    |""       |""      |
|3 |James     |Moser    |48256   |
```

How to remove the double quote when registering?

Thank you very much by advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have empty string in your data frame, if you want to write them as nulls, you can replace empty string with null, and then set `nullValues=None` when saving it:

```
df.replace('', None)              # replace empty string with null
  .write.save(
    path('out'), 
    format='csv', 
    delimiter='|', 
    header=True, 
    nullValue=None                # write null value as None
  )
```

And it will saved as:

```
id|first_name|last_name|zip_code
1||Elsner|57315
2|Noelle||
3|James|Moser|48256
```

Comment: In my case its printing None

Answer (score 7):

According to [Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/readwriter.html#DataFrameWriter.csv), the default value of both `nullValue` and `emptyValue` is `None`, and will result in an empty string.
To set it to actual *nothing*, as you desire, you can set it to the Unicode `NULL`:

```py
df.write.save(
    path('out'),
    format = 'csv',
    delimiter = '|',
    header = True,
    nullValue = '\u0000',
    emptyValue = '\u0000'
)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for the PySpark way of doing this, don't try to use the null string trick! It's much more straight-forward (once you know the trick...)

```
myDF.coalesce(1).write\
    .option("emptyValue", None)\
    .option("nullValue", None)\
    .csv(outFile)
```

Hope it helps! Couldn't find it documented anywhere

Answer (score 3):

none of the solutions above worked for me, but they were helpful to guide me to the right direction. What ended up working was adding the option `emptyValue=u'\u0000'` (when I tried without the preceding `u` it ended up writing `\u0000` literary to the csv file)

Answer (score 2):

data.write.format("csv").option("delimiter","|").option("emptyValue", "").option("nullValue", "").option("header","true").mode("overwrite").save("C:\data\test2")

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and I found my way here. After reading the solutions I went on to the [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.4.3/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py)
and discovered something funny. So there are 2 variants of writing a DF using CSV format in pyspark **without quoting the empty values** in the DF:

1. By creating and mutating a `DataFrameWriter` object:

   ```py
   df.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite")\
       .option("header", True)\
       .option("sep", "|")\
       .option("quoteAll", False)\
       .option("emptyValue", "")\
       .save("s3://...")
   ```
2. By creating a `DataFrameWriter` object and calling the `csv()` method:

   ```py
   df.write.csv(
       path="s3://...",
       mode="overwrite",
       sep="|",
       header=True,
       quoteAll=False,
       emptyValue="",
   )
   ```

The funny things I found are these:

1. Option 2 has a "[None value filter](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/c3e32bf06c35ba2580d46150923abfa795b4446a/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py#L55-L57)" but option 1 doesn't
2. In option 1, setting `option("emptyValue", None)` is equivalent as setting `option("emptyValue", "")`
3. In option 2, setting `emptyValue=None` doesn't do anything because it's going to be ignored.

Since Spark is using [univocity](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers) to deal with CSV, I dug into its code too. My guesses are:

1. `univocity` has a parameter called `quoteNulls`. By default, it's `true`
2. The default value for `emptyValue` seems to be `null`, which means empty values `""` will be replaced with `null`. Combined with `quotedNulls=true`, all empty values are quoted by default.

These are only my guesses because I don't fully understand certain code segments in `univocity`. For more details, see the [issue](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/issues/489) I just opened.

Answer (score 0):

While writing the final output - by adding option("nullValue", '').option("emptyValue", '') worked for me - it replaced "" with a blank.